# Issue importing css/js file in vuejs 2 component

Tags: node.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-loader

I have the following .vue component file:

```
<template>
....

</template>
<script>
export default { /* stuff here*/}
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

Now i would like to include some css/js (provided by the template on themeforest) files for this component only. including them within the  tag doesnt seem to work. any idea what wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide specific examples.

Comment: i just want to import some css files. ( e.g. <script type="text/javascript" src="static/assets/js/pages/login.js"></script> )

Comment: That can be done in index.html, see this [file](https://github.com/mimani/vue-example/blob/master/index.html#L13).

Comment: yes but it will be available everywhere, what i would like to have is to be available to a specific component

Answer (score 1):

Docs on how to do this: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/start/spec.html#src-imports.

```
<template src="./template.html"></template>
<style src="./style.css" scoped></style>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Note the use of `scoped` attribute. One can also use the `module` attribute instead of `scoped`. [More details](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html)